# I want to insert multiple product ID from ProductTable into another table using stored procedure sql asp.net c#

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have three tables: ProductList,PurchaseList and PurchaseDetails.on one button click, I'm trying to insert newly added products in the ProductList into the details list with the purchaseID from the purchaselist which is set to scope_identity. I'm stuck as I don't know how to insert the productIDs of the Products while scope identity gets the last ID.

My stored procedure is below:

```
@GrandTotal money,@Status varchar (20),@Method varchar (20),@Date date
as
declare @PurchaseID int
insert into PurchaseList values(@GrandTotal,@Status,@Method,@Date)
set @PurchaseID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()


insert into DetailsList(PurchaseID,ProductID)
values (@PurchaseID,)
```

I don't know what to put in the values part so I can have several productID tied to one purchasid so I can retrieve them from the DetailsList based on thier purchaseid

Comment: Where is your data structures? As of now your question is vague.

Comment: ProductList: ProductID int identity (1,1), SupplierName nvarchar(20),MedicineName nvarchar(20), price money, quantity int, amount money...... PurchaseList: PurchaseID int identity(1,1), Grandtotal money, status nvarchar(50), method nvarchar(50), purchasedate date.... DetailsList: detailID int , productID int, purchaseID int

Comment: I hope this is what u ask

Comment: Not exactly, I was trying to fill in the gaps in your question (where is missing productId in code for example). What you are really doing, anyway check my reply if that is what you meant and the only problem was scope_identity.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?:

```
DECLARE @myIDTable table (theID int);

insert into PurchaseList 
   (your field names here for grandtotal, status ...) 
   Output inserted.PurchaseId into @myIdTable 
   values (@GrandTotal,@Status,@Method,@Date);

insert into DetailsList(PurchaseID,ProductID)
select theId, yourMissingProductId
from @myIDTable;
```

Note: output clause returns you the PurchaseId values from the inserted rows (assumed your ID field was named PurchaseID). So you would have IDs of all inserted rows in a table variable @myIDTable.

Comment: Thanks cetin. Im trying to insert the id of the products i added in the productlist into the detailslist with purchaseid being the scope identity of the purchaseid in the purchase table. So i can have multiple product id to one purchase so i can retrieve the information of the products based on purchaseid when i do a join

Comment: Where is the productlist in this code? You were only inserting a single item in purchaselist. Code is above but your tables are missing, there is no insertion to productlist.